# Method Added to JavaScript Object Class Appears when Traversing through Given Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webstorm

In my journey to become stronger in JavaScript, I have taken up a challenge to add a method, `myMethod()`, to the JavaScript Object class that can be called on a given Object, `myObject`, in order to manipulate its contents.

I have gotten as far as adding `myMethod()` to the Object prototype and traversing through `myObject` via `myObject.myMethod()`; however, I'm running into a curious problem: at the end of the given object, `myMethod()` is printed as an value of `myObject` even though, to my knowledge, it should not be.

```
Object.prototype.myMethod = function()
{
    for (var key in this)
    {
        console.log(this[key]);
    }
}


function processData(input)
{
    //Enter your code here
    var myObject = JSON.parse("{ \"myParam\": \"myValue\", \"anotherParam\": 123 }");
    myObject.myMethod();
}
```

The following is the output of this code:

```
myValue
123
[Function]
```

Changing `myObject[key]` to `myObject[key].toString()` has the following output:

```
myValue
123
function ()
{
    for (var key in this)
    {
        console.log(this[key].toString());
    }
}
```

I am executing this script in WebStorm using a Node.js runtime.

The requirements of this challenge only calls for the contents of `myObject`, and I can't figure out how to stop `myMethod()` from showing up here. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my journey to become stronger in JavaScript, I have taken up a challenge to add a method, `myMethod()`, to the JavaScript `Object` class that can be called on a given `Object`, `myObject`, in order to manipulate its contents.

Beware that this practice is **seriously** frowned-upon (here in 2017, possibly more than it strictly necessary*). Extending any built-in prototype is a bit fraught, but extending `Object.prototype` is particularly problematic since, of course, almost all objects inherit from it.

But if you're going to extend a prototype, it's important to add a **non-enumerable** property via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or similar:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "myMethod", {
    value: function() { /* ... */ }
});
```

The default for `enumerable` is `false`, so it won't show up in `for-in` loops, `Object.keys` arrays, etc.

---

* The "don't extend built-in prototypes" mantra started before ES5's introduction of a way of defining non-enumerable properties (e.g., `defineProperty`). Now that we can define non-enumerable properties, the chief concern is inter-script conflict, each trying to use the same name for something, or conflict with new features as they're added to JavaScript.

Comment: Beat me to it, but can I just point out a missing comma after the `prop` parameter in your `defineProperty` call.

Comment: This was a very informative answer. Thank you! I'll keep that bit about not extending built-in prototypes in mind over my career.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.defineProperty()`.

The Object class is used in a lot of libraries and frameworks and therefore is best left alone, but can be useful for things such as poly-fills for browser compatability.

```
if (!Object.prototype.myMethod) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'myMethod', {
        value: function() { /* customer code here */ }
    })
}
```